# splunk api returns empy search

Tags: python-3.x, splunk, urllib3, splunk-query

I am trying to query the splunk API and getting empty search as response. Not sure what is missing here.

```
import urllib3,json

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
http_noproxy = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')

def get_data():
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic <BASE64>"
    }
    url   = 'URL'
    data = {
        "output_mode": "json",
        'search': 'QUERY'
    }
    encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http_noproxy.request('POST',url, headers=headers, body=encoded_data)
    print(resp.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

I am getting below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <messages>
    <msg type="FATAL">Empty search.</msg>
  </messages>
</response>
```

Comment: one problem for sure is that you're not sending a *search* to the API in that snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to know the endpoint you are using (the URL), but the Splunk REST API does not use JSON.  Send the unencoded request as `application/text`.

See the Python example in the Splunk REST API Tutorial at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.4/RESTTUT/RESTsearches#Python_example

Comment: I am using endpoint "https://splunkapi.mydomain.com:443/services/search/jobs/export". One more strange point is if i use requests module instead of urllib3 then it works and i get the response. Not sure what is the issue with urllib3.

Comment: Thanks @RichG , using urllib.parse.urlencode did the trick.